# Program type already present: com.dropbox.core.BadResponseCodeException

Tags: android, dropbox

please i'm trying to connect my app to dropbox and i'm getting this error message. i am trying to use okhttp3downloader in my app.

```
Program type already present: com.dropbox.core.BadResponseCodeException
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.dropbox.core.BadResponseCodeException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

This is my build.gradle(Module :app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.filesactivity"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.8'
    api ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'){
        exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
    implementation files('libs/dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.8.jar')
}
```

please any help will appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have three Dropbox entries in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.8'
```

...

```
implementation files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
implementation files('libs/dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.8.jar')
```

To integrate with the Dropbox API, you only need that first one, so remove the other two and try again.

Comment: Did you resync and rebuild your project? Try cleaning it as well.

Comment: Did you remove the Dropbox .jar files themselves too? It looks like you're pulling in all jars via your `implementation fileTree` line anyway, so if you still have the files, they'd appear to get imported anyway.